# Click event compare in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Is that possible to apply the below code as the radio buttons logic?

For example, apply `toggleClass` to a unique clicked div and not to each one (as you do with radio buttons).
I suppose it has to be compared which one is clicked, but how?

File has been saved to: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQ5T80AAQUC9

```js
$('#C1,#C2,#C3').click(function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('w3-light-gray w3-green');
    });
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div id="C1" class='w3-light-gray'><i> THIS IS div 1</i> </div ><br><br>
<div id="C2" class='w3-light-gray'><i>THIS IS div 2</i> </div ><br><br>
<div id="C3" class='w3-light-gray'><i> THIS IS div 3</i> </div >
```

Comment: you mean using radio button instead of a click right ?

Comment: no no, the logic is like radio buttons. My logic right now is like checkboxes. It adds background to every clicked div. I want to add only to 1 of these on each click

Comment: For example, when you click div1 and div2 , only div 2 should have green background

Comment: Question needs a far better explanation of whatever the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a div is clicked, check if it has the class `w3-green`, if it doesn't then remove that class from the div that has it and assign it to the current div:

```js
$('#C1,#C2,#C3').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.hasClass("w3-green")) {
        $(".w3-green").toggleClass('w3-light-gray w3-green');
        $this.toggleClass('w3-light-gray w3-green');
    }
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div id="C1" class='w3-light-gray'><i> THIS IS div 1</i> </div ><br><br>
<div id="C2" class='w3-light-gray'><i>THIS IS div 2</i> </div ><br><br>
<div id="C3" class='w3-light-gray'><i> THIS IS div 3</i> </div >
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to remove highlighting from all elements before you toggle the clicked element.  Just add this line before the toggleClass:

```
$('#C1,#C2,#C3').removeClass('w3-green').addClass('w3-light-gray');
```

```js
$('#C1,#C2,#C3').click(function(e) {
        $('#C1,#C2,#C3').removeClass('w3-green').addClass('w3-light-gray');
        $(this).toggleClass('w3-light-gray w3-green');
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div id="C1" class='w3-light-gray'><i> THIS IS div 1</i> </div ><br><br>
<div id="C2" class='w3-light-gray'><i>THIS IS div 2</i> </div ><br><br>
<div id="C3" class='w3-light-gray'><i> THIS IS div 3</i> </div >
```